# Comparar uma letra em um vetor de String no java?

Tags: java, array, string

Estou  fazendo um exercício em Java, sobre String, basicamente tenho que entrar com uma frase com no máximo 50 palavras separadas por espaço simples, após isso verificar se todas as palavras começam com a mesma letra, podendo a letra ser maiúscula ou minúscula.

Eu consegui transformar a String que recebe a frase e um vetor, porém não consigo achar uma maneira de verificar se as palavras de cada posição do vetor tem a mesma letra.
Ai preciso apenas de uma ajuda, uma luz ou uma iluminação pra resolver essa parte.

Segue o código do que eu consegui fazer até o momento.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Uri1140 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String frase = sc.nextLine();

        while (frase != "*") {
            String sentenca = frase;
            String[] vetor = sentenca.split(" ");
            frase = sc.nextLine();
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Jacqueline bem vinda ao SO, edite a sua pergunta e inclua o código que você já conseguiu fazer, sem ele é difícil ajudar

Comment: Desculpe-me fechar a sua pergunta, mas isso é mais um caso de usar `==` ao invés de `equals`.

Comment: Basta iterar pelo vetor, pegando a primeira letra de cada string: https://ideone.com/e4NHWL - outro detalhe é que vc [não deve fechar o `System.in`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380458/112052)