# Erro de compilação: “Resource leak” ao usar Scanner

Tags: java

Não consigo compilar o meu código pois aparece o seguinte erro abaixo:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '0'
> at java.base/java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2732)
> at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2708)
> at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2655)
> at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209)
> at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1105)
> at Teste/Exemplos.TestandoNovamentePqDeuRuim.main(TestandoNovamentePqDeuRuim.java:24)

segue o código completo:

```
package Exemplos;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestandoNovamentePqDeuRuim {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);

        
        double tempoDuracao;
        double horas;
        double minutos;
        double segundos;
        
        System.out.println("Digite o tempo de duração do evento em segundos: ");
        tempoDuracao = leia.nextDouble();
        
        horas = (tempoDuracao / 3600);
        minutos = ((tempoDuracao % 3600) / 60);
        segundos = ((tempoDuracao % 3600) % 60);
        
        System.out.printf("Horas: %0.f \nMinutos: %.0f \nSegundos: %.0f", horas,minutos,segundos);
    }

}
```

Comment: Em `Horas: %0.f`, você trocou o `0` e o `.` de lugar, deveria ser `Horas: %.0f` - isso resolve o `UnknownFormat`

Comment: Quanto ao "Resource leak", provavelmente é um *warning* (um aviso que não impede a compilação, caso contrário nem teria conseguido rodar o programa). Ele acontece porque o recurso (no caso, o `Scanner`) não está sendo fechado. De forma geral, vc deve fechar qualquer recurso que abre, mas **nesse caso específico**, como se trata do `System.in`, [não precisa fechar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380458/112052)

Answer (score -2):

Leia os comentários do código abaixo:

```
package dev.douglasmoura.utfpr;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);
        double tempoDuracao;
        double horas;
        double minutos;
        double segundos;

        System.out.println("Digite o tempo de duração do evento em segundos: ");
        tempoDuracao = leia.nextDouble();

        horas = (tempoDuracao / 3600);
        minutos = ((tempoDuracao % 3600) / 60);
        segundos = ((tempoDuracao % 3600) % 60);

        // Neste caso, o recurso será fechado automaticamente 
        // no encerramento do programa, mas adquira o hábito
        // de sempre liberar da memória os recursos que não serão
        // mais utilizados.
        leia.close();

        // Use o %n para quebrar linha, conforme a documentação: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html
        System.out.printf("Horas: %.2f %nMinutos: %.2f %nSegundos: %.2f %n", horas, minutos, segundos);
        // ------------------------^
        // Formata o valor com duas casas decimais. O . (ponto) vem antes do número.
    }
}
```