# Regex para obter trechos diferentes de um arquivo

Tags: java, regex

Preciso fazer um regex que pegue o endereço da pessoa.

Posso receber 2 tipos de texto com o endereço. No primeiro caso ele vem sozinho, e pego com esta regex:

```
"(?!/\d{1,5}\)\s/)+?\d{1,5}\)\s(.+?)\nNúmero"
```

Até aí tudo bem. Meu problema é no segundo caso que o txt me traz 2 endereços juntos.

Caso 1:

```
…(685) R. Bolonha
Passa Vinte
Palhoça - SC CEP: 00000-000
Número …
```

Caso 2:

```
..(783) R. Papa Paulo VI  Endereço Entrega
Ponte do Imaruim (4398) R. SANTA TEREZA 
Palhoça - SC CEP: 000000-000 Balneário
Florianópolis - SC CEP: 000000-000
  CADASTRO DO CLIENTE
RES COM PÚB IND TOTAL Número..
```

E nesses casos tenho que pegar somente " R. Papa Paulo VI Ponte do Imaruim Palhoça - SC CEP: 000000" que no caso seria o primeiro endereço.

Preciso pegar o Endereço com somente com 1 regex nos 2 casos, tem como?

Os dados são fictícios, e as reticências significam que o texto continua.

Comment: Não entendi. Nos dois casos vc só quer a rua (sem o número), cidade, estado e CEP? A string `Endereço Entrega` pode estar lá? Existem outras variações no formato? Quanto mais variações e possibilidades, mais complexa é a regex. E porque o segundo CEP tem 6 dígitos? Aliás, o segundo exemplo tem dois CEPs em duas cidades diferentes, não é para pegar a segunda? Se puder por favor [edit] a pergunta e deixar um pouco mais claro...

Comment: então, ai que esta meu problema no primeiro ele so retorna 1 endereço, ja no segundo caso ele retorna 2, ai tenha que pegar somente o primeiro endereço

Comment: Pra mim ainda não está claro. O que são esses números entre parênteses? No segundo caso, por que o resultado é "R. Papa Paulo VI Ponte do Imaruim Palhoça", se o trecho "Ponte do Imaruim" parece fazer parte do outro endereço (da R Santa Tereza)? Se tem que ignorar a R. Santa Tereza, porque não foi ignorado o trecho "Ponte do Imaruim" que está na mesma linha? Aliás, os dados ficam sempre em linhas separadas? Sem saber o critério exato (onde começa e termina um endereço, quais dados considerar, etc) fica difícil dar uma resposta precisa, ainda mais com regex, onde precisão faz toda a diferença

Comment: os numeros entre () são algum tipo de id, esses dados são de um pdf, que são tranformados em txt e entregues para mim,  eles sempre vem no formato 1 ou no formato 2

Comment: ele sempre começam pelo primeiro id do primeiro endereço \\(\\d{1,5}\\), so que não termina com o mesmo valor

Comment: eu to tentando pegar as linhas separadas, mas so consigo pegar a rua, o bairro e cidade não consigo. peguei rua assim "(?!/\\d{1,5}\\)\\s/)+?\\d{1,5}\\)\\s(.+?)(\\n|Endereço)"

Comment: Bom, coloquei uma solução mais simplificada que acho que vai servir (pelo menos para os exemplos citados na pergunta). Mas acho que uma única regex que faz tudo é complicado demais, por isso usei 3 regex separadas...

Comment: Henrique, se vc achou uma solução, basta adicionar uma resposta abaixo (é melhor pois assim o site fica mais organizado, com a pergunta separada das respostas). Até pq eu fiquei curioso pra ver o seu código, já que fazendo um teste com a sua regex, não obtive o mesmo resultado... :-)

Comment: respondi, sua resposta me ajudou bastante muito obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUÇÃO**

consegui fazer um regex q pega tudo, mas em grupos diferentes

```
(?!/\\d{1,}\\)\\s/)+?\\d{1,}\\)\\s(.+?)(\\n|Endereço(.+?)\\n)(.+?)(\\n|\\((.+?)\\n)(.+?)CEP:\\s(.+?)\\s
```

rua = grupo 1

bairro = grupo 4

cidade = grupo 7

cep = grupo 8

esse é o metodo que utilizo para fazer os regex

```
public static final String executeRegexp(final String text, final String er, final int group) {
        final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(er, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(text);
        final boolean match = matcher.find();
        if (!match) {
            log.info("no match " + er);
            return "";
        }
        return matcher.group(group);
    }
```

Comment: Fiz uns testes e acho que o trecho `(?!/\\d{1,}\\)\\s/)+?` não é necessário. Esse é um *negative lookahead*, que verifica se algo não existe à frente. E dentro dele tem uma barra, seguida de dígitos, `)`, espaço e outra barra. E como não tem barras na string, este trecho nunca dará *match* (mas como é um negative lookbehind, ele sempre funciona nesse caso, então é redundante e desnecessário - além de deixar a regex mais lenta, pois toda hora tem que verificar se isso existe, quando ela poderia já buscar o restante da expressão sem precisar disso)

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*Seria interessante ter mais detalhes sobre o formato exato do arquivo e mais alguns exemplos, mas de qualquer forma, vou deixar uma solução mais geral, e você adapta de acordo com o que precisar.*</sup>

---

Para esta solução, criei um arquivo baseado nas informações da pergunta e dos comentários:

```
(685) R. Bolonha
Passa Vinte
Palhoça - SC CEP: 00000-000
Número
(783) R. Papa Paulo VI  Endereço Entrega
Ponte do Imaruim (4398) R. SANTA TEREZA 
Palhoça - SC CEP: 00000-000 Balneário
Florianópolis - SC CEP: 00000-000
  CADASTRO DO CLIENTE
RES COM PÚB IND TOTAL Número
```

Algumas premissas que considerei:

- a primeira linha contém um número entre parênteses, seguido do nome da própria rua/avenida, etc.

  - opcionalmente pode ter o texto "Endereço Entrega" no final da linha
  - pelo que entendi, não tem o número do endereço, somente o nome da rua
- as linhas que contém o CEP sempre estão no formato "cidade - UF CEP: 00000-000"

  - considerei que o CEP com 6 dígitos antes do hífen é um erro de digitação, então estou buscando sempre no formato "5 dígitos, hífen, 3 dígitos"
- no caso de ter um segundo endereço, ele aparece na mesma linha do bairro do primeiro endereço - ou seja, considerei que "Ponte de Imaruim" é o bairro do primeiro endereço (R. Papa Paulo VI) e a R. Santa Tereza é o segundo endereço

  - se tiver uma lista de vários CEPs seguidos, o primeiro que aparecer é o que vale, qualquer outro que vier logo depois é ignorado
- se a linha começa com o ID (número entre parênteses), então este é o primeiro endereço, e o bairro e CEP que tiver depois referem-se a ele
- não há casos em que a rua ou o CEP estão na mesma linha, ou que hajam outras informações que não as informadas nos exemplos

Repare que são muitas premissas e "achismos" da minha parte, mas é o que dá para fazer com as informações que foram passadas. De qualquer forma, se o arquivo realmente não tiver um formato bem definido, não há muito o que fazer a não ser começar de um ponto e ir ajustando de acordo, conforme novos casos surgirem.

Dito isso, não acho que vale a pena usar uma única regex gigante que faz tudo. Eu acho melhor ir lendo o arquivo linha a linha, e para cada caso você usa uma regex diferente, pois como são muitas variações, cada regex individualmente já é (ou pode se tornar) complicada por si só.

---

Uma primeira tentativa (baseada unicamente no arquivo de teste que gerei acima), seria:

```java
Pattern regexRua = Pattern.compile("^\\(\\d{1,5}\\) (.+?)(?:\\s*Endereço Entrega)?$");
Pattern regexBairro = Pattern.compile("^([^(]+)");
Pattern regexCep = Pattern.compile("^(.+) - ([A-Z]{2}) CEP: (\\d{5}-\\d{3})$");
int status = 0; // 0=rua, 1=bairro, 2=CEP
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/caminho/do/arquivo.txt"))) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String texto = sc.nextLine();
        switch (status) {
            case 0:
                Matcher matcherRua = regexRua.matcher(texto);
                if (matcherRua.find()) {
                    String rua = matcherRua.group(1).trim();
                    System.out.printf("Endereço: %s\n", rua);
                    status = 1; // consegui ler o endereço, passo para o bairro
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                Matcher matcherBairro = regexBairro.matcher(texto);
                if (matcherBairro.find()) {
                    String bairro = matcherBairro.group(1);
                    System.out.printf("Bairro: %s\n", bairro);
                    status = 2; // consegui ler o bairro, passo para a cidade/uf/cep
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                Matcher matcherCep = regexCep.matcher(texto);
                if (matcherCep.find()) {
                    String cidade = matcherCep.group(1);
                    String uf = matcherCep.group(2);
                    String cep = matcherCep.group(3);
                    System.out.printf("Cidade: %s, UF: %s, CEP: %s\n", cidade, uf, cep);
                    status = 0; // consegui ler cidade/uf/cep, volto a ler o próximo endereço
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Primeiro eu uso um [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052) para abrir o arquivo, e vou lendo linha a linha (não coloquei um bloco `catch` para manter o foco no algoritmo, mas no seu código final, [coloque-o e trate os erros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/112052)).

Eu uso uma variável de status para saber qual informação estou lendo atualmente. A lógica é: eu tento ler o endereço (a linha que começa com o ID - um número entre parênteses), se conseguir, eu tento ler o bairro. E se conseguir ler o bairro, eu tento ler a cidade/UF/CEP (e se conseguir, volto para tentar ler o próximo endereço).

Se a informação que estou tentando ler atualmente não é encontrada, ele passa a próxima linha, e assim vai, até o final do arquivo. A saída é:

```
Endereço: R. Bolonha
Bairro: Passa Vinte
Cidade: Palhoça, UF: SC, CEP: 00000-000
Endereço: R. Papa Paulo VI
Bairro: Ponte do Imaruim 
Cidade: Florianópolis, UF: SC, CEP: 00000-000
```

---

## Sobre as regex

Agora vamos ver alguns detalhes de cada regex.

### Endereço

Para o endereço eu usei:

```
Pattern regexRua = Pattern.compile("^\\(\\d{1,5}\\) (.+?)(?:\\s*Endereço Entrega)?$");
```

Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Depois eu verifico o ID (de 1 a 5 dígitos entre parênteses, seguindo a mesma regex que você usou na pergunta). Note que os parênteses devem estar escapados com `\` (que dentro de uma `String` devem ser escritos como `\\`), já que eles são caracteres com significado especial em regex (veremos isso logo abaixo), e para que a regex entenda que queremos os próprios caracteres `(` e `)`, precisamos do escape com `\`.

Depois temos um espaço, seguido de `.+?` (um ou mais caracteres). Este trecho está dentro de parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), pois assim eu consigo recuperar este trecho depois, usando o método [`group`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-).

Depois temos `\\s*` (zero ou mais espaços), seguido de "Endereço Entrega". E o `?` torna este trecho [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html). E também uso `(?:` para que este par de parênteses não se torne um grupo de captura (pois eu não preciso recuperar este trecho depois, e assim a regex não precisa criar grupos à toa).

O trecho `.+?` é uma simplificação, pois pega tudo que estiver na linha (depois do ID e antes de "Endereço Entrega", caso exista). Um detalhe é que se você usar apenas `.+`, ele pega a linha inteira (inclusive "Endereço Entrega"), pois o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) é ganancioso e tenta pegar o máximo possível de caracteres. Para evitar esse comportamento, usa-se a sintaxe `.+?`.

Com isso, a regex terá o endereço no grupo 1 (pois é o primeiro par de parênteses), e é isso que é feito quando usamos `matcherRua.group(1)`. Eu também uso o método [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) para remover eventuais espaços do início e fim.

### Bairro

Para o bairro, temos:

```
Pattern regexBairro = Pattern.compile("^([^(]+)");
```

Essa é um pouco mais simples, e eu fiz uma simplificação **bem** grosseira, pois me baseei no formato indicado na pergunta.

Ela possui o início da string (`^`) e depois usa `[^(]+`: um ou mais caracteres que não sejam o `(`. Isso quer dizer que no primeiro caso ("Passa Vinte"), ela pega a linha inteira, e no segundo caso ("Ponte do Imaruim (4398) R. SANTA TEREZA"), ela pega tudo até o `(` - ou seja, apenas o trecho "Ponte de Imaruim " (com o espaço no final inclusive, por isso eu também uso `trim()` aqui).

Um ponto importante é que, graças a variável de status, eu garanto que só vou ler o bairro se anteriormente eu consegui ler o endereço. Isso quer dizer que o arquivo deve ter o bairro logo depois do endereço (caso contrário, esta regex também poderia pegar as linhas como "CADASTRO DO CLIENTE", por exemplo - Na verdade, até mesmo a linha do CEP poderia ser confundida com um bairro, já que `[^(]` é "**qualquer** caractere que não seja `(`", então a linha do CEP também se encaixaria nesse caso).

Esse é mais um motivo para não usar uma única regex gigante, pois ficaria bem mais complexo diferenciar um texto que é um bairro de um texto genérico. E é também baseada na premissa de que o formato do arquivo estará sempre correto, com o bairro logo abaixo do endereço.

### Cidade/UF/CEP

Para a cidade, UF e CEP, temos:

```
Pattern regexCep = Pattern.compile("^(.+) - ([A-Z]{2}) CEP: (\\d{5}-\\d{3})$");
```

Ela também usa `^` e `$` para demarcar o início e fim da string. Depois temos 3 grupos de captura (3 pares de parênteses):

- o primeiro, para a cidade, usa a expressão ultra-simplificada `.+` (um ou mais caracteres)
- o segundo, para a UF, usa `[A-Z]{2}` (duas letras maiúsculas)
- o terceiro, para o CEP usa `\\d{5}-\\d{3}` (5 dígitos, hífen, 3 dígitos)

A parte da UF e CEP estão bem definidas, já para a cidade eu fui bem preguiçoso, pois estou me apoiando no formato do arquivo: se é garantido que esta linha sempre terá o formato acima, a regex vai capturar tudo corretamente, então eu não preciso me preocupar se no nome da cidade tiver coisas sem sentido como `!@#$%*-x` (pois estou assumindo que não terá casos assim).

Aliás, o mesmo vale para o bairro e endereço. Se você sabe que o arquivo sempre trará nomes válidos, pode usar as regex mais simples acima. Mas se quiser fazer validações mais complexas (como "a cidade tem que ter X letras", "o endereço tem que começar com R. ou Av.", etc), aí as expressões vão ficando cada vez maiores e mais complexas.

Mas creio que com a solução acima você já tenha por onde começar.