# Ler dados de um arquivo e guardar em um Set, mas o Set está nulo

Tags: java, java-8, hashset

Estou a tentar ler um arquivo txt, selecionar uma coluna específica chamada "customerid", pegar todos os valores dessa coluna e mostrar na tela quantos valores diferentes existem.

Porém, quando tento isso, o `HashSet` sempre me retorna valor `null`. Não estou a conseguir entender qual o meu erro ou onde não estou a carregar os dados de forma correta. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Código:

```
package com.nayana.exercicio1.methods;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.HashSet;


public class Methods {

    private BufferedReader file;
    private HashSet<String> customer;
    private int lines;
    private String[] columns;
    public String line;


    //INPUT PARA O ARQUIVOO A SER LIDO

    public BufferedReader getFile() {
        return file;
    }


    public void setFile(BufferedReader file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.file = file;
    }

    //CONTAR NÚMERO DE LINHAS EXISTENTES
    public int getLines() {
        return lines;
    }

    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }
    public void setLines(int lines) throws IOException {
        this.lines = lines;
        }

    public String[] getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(String[] columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
        columns = ((String)line).split(";");
    }
    public void setLine(String line) throws IOException {
        this.line = file.readLine();
    }


    public void contarLinhas() throws Exception {

        while((line = file.readLine()) !=null) {

            setColumns(columns);
            lines++;

        }}



    //CONTAR QUANTOS COSTUMERID DIFERENTES EXISTEM

    public  HashSet<String> getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(HashSet<String> customer) throws IOException {
        this.customer =  new HashSet<String>();



    }

    public void customerId() throws Exception {
        setFile(file);
        while((line = file.readLine()) !=null) {
            String [] columns = line.split(";");


            customer.add(columns[4]); 

            customer.size();
        setCustomer(customer);
        }
    }

    //SALTAR LINHA

    public void saltarLinha() throws IOException {
        line = file.readLine();

    }


    //MOSTRAR NA TELA


    public void status(){
    System.out.println("\nO número total de linhas é: " + getLines());
    System.out.println("\nO número total de CustomerId é: " + getCustomer());
    }
```

Main:

```
package com.nayana.exercicio1;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;


import com.nayana.exercicio1.methods.Methods;



public class Exercicio1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Methods exercicio = new Methods();

        exercicio.setFile(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\nayan\\Downloads\\orders_04_20_07.txt")));

        exercicio.contarLinhas();
        exercicio.saltarLinha();
        exercicio.customerId();
        exercicio.status();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem vários problemas no código, entre eles:

- você tenta ler o arquivo duas vezes (uma no método `contarLinhas` e outra no método `customerId`). O problema é que a primeira vez já lê o arquivo todo, e na segunda vez não haverá mais nada a ser lido
- no método `contarLinhas` você faz `setColumns(columns)`, mas esse `columns` que você está passando é o campo `columns` da própria classe (ou seja, você tenta atribuir ele a ele mesmo). E o grande problema é que em nenhum momento ele é inicializado, por isso ele estará `null`.

Mas acho que o principal problema é a estrutura da classe em si. Nem tudo precisa ser um campo, nem tudo precisa de *getter* e *setter*, e o processo de leitura do arquivo não precisa ficar tão "modularizado" assim. Uma sugestão seria deixar o código assim:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Methods {

    private Set<String> customers = new HashSet<>();

    private int lines = 0;

    public void lerArquivo(String arquivo) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivo))) {
            while (reader.ready()) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                String[] columns = line.split(";");
                this.customers.add(columns[4]);
                this.lines++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void status() {
        System.out.println("\nO número total de linhas é: " + this.lines);
        System.out.println("\nO número total de CustomerId é: " + this.customers.size());
    }
}
```

E no `main`, faça:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Methods exercicio = new Methods();
    exercicio.lerArquivo("C:\\Users\\nayan\\Downloads\\orders_04_20_07.txt");
    exercicio.status();
}
```

Repare que somente `lines` e `customers` precisam ser campos da classe, o restante só é usado no método que lê o arquivo (nem o próprio arquivo precisa de um *setter*, é um exagero - na verdade é só desnecessário mesmo). Eu inicializo esses campos na própria declaração, mas nada impede que isso seja feito em um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052) também. E note que mudei o nome para `customers` (no plural), já que ele pode ter mais de um (pode parecer um detalhe bobo, mas [nomes significativos ajudam na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad)).

Note que também usei o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052), que fecha o arquivo automaticamente no final (sintaxe válida para Java >= 7). Só não coloquei um bloco `catch` por "preguiça" (*mentira, foi para deixar o exemplo mais simples, já que a finalidade é mais didática...*), mas pode colocar também caso deseje tratar o eventual erro de leitura no arquivo (mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/112052)).

Na leitura, eu preencho o `Set` de `customers` e conto as linhas **no mesmo *loop*** (não tem porque percorrer o arquivo duas vezes para isso). Vale notar também que `customers.add` já adiciona a nova informação no `Set`, não precisa ficar setando ele toda hora com `setCustomer`.

Aliás, removi os *getters* e *setters* porque em nenhum momento pareceu ser necessário usá-los. Dentro da própria classe eu posso simplesmente usar `this.lines` e `this.customers` (o `this` é opcional nesses casos, já que a própria classe consegue ver que se refere ao respectivo campo, mas eu costumo usar para deixar bem claro que ali estou usando um campo da própria classe).

Uma classe só deveria expor o necessário: se os valores de `lines` e `customers` dependem exclusivamente do conteúdo do arquivo, não há motivo para se ter *setters* que podem mudar os valores desses campos para qualquer coisa. E se a única forma de se verificar os seus valores é através do método `status()`, não precisa de *getters* também.

Comment: Caramba, muito obrigada mesmo. Estava há um bom tempo batendo a cabeça pra entender, mas realmente quando somos iniciantes complicamos demais algo que é até bem simples. Fico muito agradecida pela disponibilidade e por toda a explicação!