# Como utilizar o ValidationMessageFor no DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Por favor, alguém sabe me dizer como faço para utilizar o **@Html.ValidationMessageFor** para um **@Html.DropDownListFor?**
Partindo do princípio que o usuário acionou a opção de gravar da tela do sistema ele deveria informar que o campo é obrigatório; ao invés disso, o sistema está apresentando um erro:

> Valor não pode ser nulo. Nome do parâmetro: source

Parece que ao realizar o post o ViewBag fica nulo e por isso ao invés dele chamar o VilidationMessageFor ele informa o erro acima!

Desde já agradeço toda ajuda!

**View**

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<label for="lblTratamento">Tratamemto <i style = "color:red;">*</i></label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Tratamento,
     ((IEnumerable<TratamentoModel>)ViewBag.Tratamento).Select(tratamento => new SelectListItem
       {
           Text = tratamento.DescricaoTratamento,
           Value = tratamento.DescricaoTratamento,
           Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.Tratamento == tratamento.DescricaoTratamento)
       }), "Escolha um Tratamento", new { @class = "form-control select2 left cmb-treatment", @id = "ddlTratamento" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tratamento, String.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;!important" })
```

**Model**

```
public class PessoaFisicaModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selecione um tratamento.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Tratamento { get; set; }
}
```

**Class (Negocio)**

```
public class TratamentoClass
    {
        public List<T> ObtemListaTratamento<T>() where T : ITratamento, new()
        {
            ModelagemDados db = new ModelagemDados();

            try
            {
                var listaTratamento = db.Tratamento.Select(
                x => new T()
                {
                    CodigoTratamento = x.CodigoTratamento,
                    DescricaoTratamento = x.DescricaoTratamento
                }).ToList();

                return listaTratamento;
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                                                validationError.PropertyName,
                                                validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }

        }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GravarPessoaFisica(PessoaFisicaModel pessoafisica)
{
    PessoaFisicaClass _pessoaFisica = new PessoaFisicaClass();
    try
    {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
             var retorno = _pessoaFisica.GravarPessoaFisica(pessoafisica);
             if (retorno != 0)
             {
                 return RedirectToAction("Index", "CadastroCliente");
             }
                ViewBag.Message = "Erro: Por favor, reporte o ocorrido ao administrador do sistema";
           }
              return View("CadastrarCliente", pessoafisica);
            }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
             foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
             {
                 Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                                         validationError.PropertyName,
                                         validationError.ErrorMessage);
        }
             }
     return ViewBag.Message == "Contate o administrador do sistema, Erro: " + dbEx.Message.ToString();
            }
}
```

**Controller (Carga de Dados)**

```
public ActionResult CadastrarCliente(string user)
{
     var retornoEstado = new EstadoClass().ObtemLista<EstadoModel>();
     var retornoCidadeIbge = new CidadeIbgeClass().ObtemLista<CidadeIbgeModel>();
     var retornoBanco = new BancoClass().ObtemLista<BancoModel>();
     var retornoSitucao = new SituacaoClass().ObtemLista<SituacaoModel>();
     var retornoOrgao = new OrgaoClass().ObtemListaOrgao<OrgaoModel>();
     var retornoLotacao = new LotacaoClass().ObtemListaLotacao<LotacaoModel>();
     var retornoTratamento = new TratamentoClass().ObtemListaTratamento<TratamentoModel>();
     var retornoEstadoCivil = new EstadoCivilClass().ObtemLista<EstadoCivilModel>();
     var retornoTipoTelefone = new TipoTelefoneClass().ObtemLista<TipoTelefoneModel>();
     var retornoCargo = new CargoClass().ObtemLista<CargoModel>();
     ViewBag.Estado = retornoEstado;
     ViewBag.CidadeIbge = retornoCidadeIbge;
     ViewBag.Banco = retornoBanco;
     ViewBag.Situacao = retornoSitucao;
     ViewBag.Orgao = retornoOrgao;
     ViewBag.Lotacao = retornoLotacao;
     ViewBag.Tratamento = retornoTratamento;
     ViewBag.EstadoCivil = retornoEstadoCivil;
     ViewBag.TipoTelefone = retornoTipoTelefone;
     ViewBag.Cargo = retornoCargo;
     return View();
}
```

Comment: Você quer apenas colocar a mensagem de `required` ao submeter o formulário ou a mensagem retornada do servidor (aquela que geralmente é vermelha)?

Comment: Como está a *Action* do *Controller* que recebe os dados a serem validados?

Comment: Randrade e Cigano Morrison Mendez  muito obrigado por responder, eu atualizei a pergunta, eu identifiquei também que parece que a ViewBag que estou utilizando para carregar o DropDownList fica com valor nulo quando e acionado o botão de gravar que realiza post no formulário. Obrigado novamente!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ainda estão faltando algumas coisas. Este erro que você teve significa que as informações do formulário não passaram pela validação, a *View* retornará preenchida com os erros e todas as *DropDowns* precisam ser carregadas novamente. Como não foram carregadas novamente, `@Html.DropDownListFor` reclama de um `source` nulo.

Em resumo, a alteração é no *Controller*. Meus comentários estão pelo código. Peço para que leia todos:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GravarPessoaFisica(PessoaFisicaModel pessoafisica)
{
    PessoaFisicaClass _pessoaFisica = new PessoaFisicaClass();
    try // Controllers não devem tratar exceções.
    // Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21278/como-interceptar-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-quando-se-trabalha-com-o-entity-framework/21343#21343
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var retorno = _pessoaFisica.GravarPessoaFisica(pessoafisica);
            if (retorno != 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "CadastroCliente");
            }

            // Que ocorrido? 
            // O usuário não tem que reportar coisa alguma.
            // Você que tem que interceptar a exceção internamente usando 
            // uma ferramenta e apenas devolver mensagem de erro que a 
            // operação falhou.
            ViewBag.Message = "Erro: Por favor, reporte o ocorrido ao administrador do sistema";
        }

        // Repita aqui a carga da Action GET     
        ViewBag.Estado = new EstadoClass().ObtemLista<EstadoModel>();
        ViewBag.CidadeIbge = new CidadeIbgeClass().ObtemLista<CidadeIbgeModel>();
        ViewBag.Banco = new BancoClass().ObtemLista<BancoModel>();
        ViewBag.Situacao = new SituacaoClass().ObtemLista<SituacaoModel>();
        ViewBag.Orgao = new OrgaoClass().ObtemListaOrgao<OrgaoModel>();
        ViewBag.Lotacao = new LotacaoClass().ObtemListaLotacao<LotacaoModel>();
        ViewBag.Tratamento = new TratamentoClass().ObtemListaTratamento<TratamentoModel>();
        ViewBag.EstadoCivil = new EstadoCivilClass().ObtemLista<EstadoCivilModel>();
        ViewBag.TipoTelefone = new TipoTelefoneClass().ObtemLista<TipoTelefoneModel>();
        ViewBag.Cargo = new CargoClass().ObtemLista<CargoModel>();

        return View("CadastrarCliente", pessoafisica);
    }
    // Este catch deve ser movido para SaveChanges() e SaveChangesAsync() do contexto.
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                                         validationError.PropertyName,
                                         validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        return ViewBag.Message == "Contate o administrador do sistema, Erro: " + dbEx.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Cigano Morrison Mendez

Comment: @WiliansMartins A resposta atendeu ao seu problema? [Veja aqui os próximos passos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!

Comment: Com certeza atendeu, muito obrigado!