# Erro ao Salvar alterações EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Boa noite,

Ao tentar inserir os dados na tabela me da o erro "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.".

```
var db = new Repositorio();
            var perfilPessoaDB = Objeto.ConverterParaEntidade<PerfilPessoaFisica, tbPerfilPessoaFisica>(perfilPessoa);
            perfilPessoaDB.tbPerfilPessoaFisicaObjetivo = Objeto.ConverterParaEntidade<PerfilPessoaFisicaObjetivo, tbPerfilPessoaFisicaObjetivo>(perfilPessoa.Objetivo);
            perfilPessoaDB.tbPerfilPessoaFisicaObjetivoS = Objeto.ConverterParaEntidade<PerfilPessoaFisicaObjetivo, tbPerfilPessoaFisicaObjetivo>(perfilPessoa.ObjetivoSecundario);
            perfilPessoaDB.TbUsuario = Objeto.ConverterParaEntidade<Usuario, TbUsuario>(perfilPessoa.Alterador);
            db.tbPerfilPessoaFisica.Add(perfilPessoaDB);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como corrigir o EntityValidationErrors](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17644/como-corrigir-o-entityvalidationerrors)

Comment: Não sei se é duplicata de fato.

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente o erro esta ocorrendo por que alguma propriedade não deve está preenchida.
Utiliza try catch para debugar e encontrar o erro:

```
try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando a exceção estourar no Visual Studio, clique em **View Detail...**. Uma janela irá abrir na qual você pode expandir o nó **Inner Exception**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]