# Como identificar a Entidade que lança o erro ao salvar?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Na minha aplicação, com Entity Framework, eu faço uma consulta em uma entidade Rodada:

```
var lista = contexto.Rodada.Where(condições);
```

Depois itero sobre essa lista com um foreach.

Durante a iteração ocorrem "updates" e "inserts" de várias entidades e uma delas é responsável pelo seguinte erro:

**The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.**

Pesquisando, eu vi que a razão desse erro é que o valor default (ou mínimo) para o datetime no c# está fora do range de valores aceitos no Sql Server:

[vide link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050906/how-to-fix-the-datetime2-out-of-range-conversion-error-using-dbcontext-and-setin)

Estou tentando localizar onde isso ocorre, mas são muitos datetimes em várias entidades, e o stack trace não me ajudou em nada. Existe alguma forma de identificar a entidade que lançou o erro?

Comment: Coloque todo o código na sua pergunta, por favor, para que seja identificado o problema? Qual versão do banco SQLServer também

Answer (score 1):

Sim. [Eu já respondi isso em outra pergunta que não é exatamente uma duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17644/como-corrigir-o-entityvalidationerrors/17648#17648).

Depois de implementar, coloque um *breakpoint* dentro do `catch`. Como são muitas entidades, provavelmente o erro deve se repetir por todas as entidades do mesmo tipo.

Não esqueça de implementar também para `SaveChangesAsync` se estiver usando métodos assíncronos para salvar.

Comment: Valeu @Cigano! Descobri que mexeram no banco e adicionaram uma coluna de data nova. Atribui o valor e voltou a funcionar. Mas vou forçar o erro e testar sua solução.